# BGINFO: line break if more than 4 IP-addresses?

Tags: windows

We have some Windows servers with many IP-addresses. They are all showing up in [BGInfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx) which is in the right corner.

When there are too much IP-adresses the whole infos are pushed in the left corner, on small monitors they get out of sight.

It would be nice to see them on the right corner. Therefor the ip-addresses have to get a line break after 4 ip-addresses.

Is this possible?
Or is there another new tool which is more suitable?